Trouble creating a dataset from h5 file
I'm having a problem regarding the h5 file. Whenever I try to load it I get this error:
OSError: Can't read data (can't open directory: /opt/conda/envs/AE4353/lib/hdf5/plugin)

I can read the file without any problem, I'm providing the right path and I have everything I need installed. However when I try to run a simple code such as the following I get the error above.
def load_h5_file(h5_file_path):
    with h5py.File(h5_file_path, "r") as file: 
        images = file["images"][:] 
        targets = file["targets"][:] 

        Images = torch.tensor(images)  
        Targets = torch.tensor(targets)  

    return Images, Targets

load_h5_file(h5_file_path)

Considering the error I tried to install the plugin but I get this error:
(AE4353_user_env) vscode ➜ /workspaces/AE4353-Y24 (main) $ conda install -c conda-forge hdf5-plugin
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - hdf5-plugin

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page.

So I went to the terminal and tried to install the specific plugin, getting the following message:
Requirement already satisfied: h5py[hdf5plugin] in /home/kibangadas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (3.11.0)
  WARNING: h5py 3.11.0 does not provide the extra 'hdf5plugin'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /home/kibangadas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from h5py[hdf5plugin]) (1.24.4)

Afterwards I tried to install the hdf5plugin separately which actually downloaded and installed it:
Collecting hdf5plugin
  Downloading hdf5plugin-5.0.0-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (45.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 45.6 MB 14.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: h5py>=3.0.0 in /home/kibangadas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from hdf5plugin) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /home/kibangadas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from h5py>=3.0.0->hdf5plugin) (1.24.4)
Installing collected packages: hdf5plugin
Successfully installed hdf5plugin-5.0.0

But in the end I kept getting the same error on vscode, any ideas how I can solve this?

Python is searching for the plugin in the conda folder "/opt/conda/envs/*", but it's actually been installed with pip. Try adding this to the top of your Python file:
import hdf5plugin


I unfortunately got this: bash: import: command not found

@Anon import is a Python command, not a bash one

Are you telling me to import on the code itself? Cause when I do I just get this back: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/workspaces/AE4353-Y24/competition/teste.py", line 27, in 
import hdf5plugin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hdf5plugin'

looks like youre on conda environment so it will not use pip, either you need to "conda install conda-forge::hdf5plugin" or make h5py to use plugin from where you installed your pip installed plugin
